# Update UIImageView with new UIImage

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios

*UPDATE***

My first description (now deleted) was'nt the real situation. It is a simplified version of the problem.

**The Complete situation:**

I want to change the UIImage within a UIImageView with a picture which I select from the iphone photo gallery.
For this I used a MediaPicker (part of the Xamarin library).

When I click a button, the Mediapicker will be created. Then I call a function to take a picture from the photo gallery. This methods expects 2 arguments. The Mediapicker and a callback function. --> PictureFromGallery(mediaPicker, CallbackPhotoMade);
 This callback function will be trigger after a user selected a picture in the photo library to upload.

Within this callback function I want to change the UIImage of the UIImageView.

```
void CallbackPhotoMade(MediaFile obj)
{
    imageviewPhoto1.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/image2.PNG");
    //To test I just use a file from a folder in my project
}
```

When I breakpoint the above function (CallbackPhotoMade) and I put my mouse at the text ".Image =", the following message apears:
**MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling an UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread**

I think this is the problem why the UIImage within the UIImageView doesn't change.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

*UPDATE2***
I read in another topic that this could be solved by setting CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false like:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
}
```

Unfortunately the image still doesn't change.
Although, the specific error dissapeared.

Comment: I have near identical code that works. Are you sure (e.g. a breakpoint) that you `ChangeImage` is being called ?

Comment: Yes I am sure the ChangeImage method is called. I've tested it with a breakpoint.

Comment: in that case check and rechek the name (capital letters?) of image2.PNG. Is it copied to applications bundle? Is it possible, that PNG is corrupt?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Check my topic update for the up-to-date status. Hopefully you can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
void CallbackPhotoMade(MediaFile obj)
{
    InvokeOnMainThread(() => { 
        imageviewPhoto1.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/image2.PNG"); 
    });
    //To test I just use a file from a folder in my project
}
```

The setting you made, just disables checking, but does not prevent the exception.

The callback is done on another thread (async). And **you can/should only update the user interface on/from the main thread**. `InvokeOnMainThread()` makes your code execute on the main thread, which is just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the code should run.
Check whether imageviewPhoto1 is nill or not in changeImage method.
If nill then your object is probably released.

If not nill then try writing [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; after setting image , just to see redrawing view can update it or not. Or try whether view is present by setting imageviewPhoto1's background color to something else.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Check my topic update for the up-to-date status. Hopefully you can help me